# Delay page close with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, delay

Now, I understand that it's bad practice to delay a page close, and that there are better ways to handle that kind of stuff, but just for future reference, is there a way to delay the page closing? Something like

```
window.onunload = unload();

function unload()
{
setTimeout("self.close()", 1000)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: @GlennSlaven, tried what? The above function doesn't work (of course :P), and I was asking if maybe there was a browser-approved way of doing it, like a function that would delay it for only one second, no more no less, or something

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really need (ie. ready to resort to semi-hacks) to delay the page closing without showing a confirmation dialog, etc, you can do something like the following:

```
function delay(ms) {
    var start = +new Date;
    while ((+new Date - start) < ms);
}

// start image loading (I assume you need this for tracking?)
delay(150);
```

The caveats are obvious: it will not always work and you cannot delay for too long. That being said, if you are really interested in this, you can probably get results of over 95% (really depends on the server response time).

Comment: But that also will lock the page and spike your CPU.  It can delay it, but you can't do anything at all during that period.  Making this hack probably not so useful.

Comment: @Squeegy It's not nearly as bad as it sounds :) You will actually not notice the "lock" if you keep the timeout around 150-250. And by the way, this is not something I've invented now, it's being used in production by visitor trackers.

Answer (score 1):

`onbeforeunload` doesn't work with timeout to protect the browser user from being.

The only way to prevent the page from exiting after the user attempts to leave is by putting synchronous code in the onbeforeunload/onunload handler

### But there is something you can do!!!

```
for(var i = 0; i < 2000; i++){
    console.log(i);
}
```

You can make this for loop printing to console to delay the unload of the page.

The higher number will take delay high to reload page.