# Delay page navigation / leaving in jQuery

Tags: jquery, navigation

I am trying to write a jQuery plugin that should logout the user before leaving the page or closing the browser. I have captured every exit point of the page (eg. f5, close tab, refresh, close browser, navigate) but when I try to send a jQuery.post() request before leaving the page, the request can not be made because the browser has no time to send the request.

Is there a way to delay any page navigation / page leaving / browser closing by 1 seconds or more so I can squeeze in a jQuery.post() request before actually leaving the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The traditional way to do this is to have the client send a request to the server every `x` minutes, to let it know the user is still active. If the server does not receive a request within a certain timeframe, it should expire the session (thus logging the user out).

Comment: I figured something like this as well, but wouldn't this require a socket connection at the least? Or is there a way to do this using php sessions?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might answer your question: [Delay page close with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350215/delay-page-close-with-javascript)

It's a buggy solution though, mainly because modern browsers don't really allow stuff like this for security reasons.

If you are using cookies to hold the session information, couldn't you destroy the cookie and therefore have the user logged out, using the onunload event?

Hope that helps.

Comment: That answer indeed explains the way to delay a page close, however it doesn't cover holding / pausing navigation or closing the page until all functions are performed.

Comment: That's because unless you want to do some serious hacking, it's not really possible as it has the potential for misuse. You can try experimenting with onunload, but I don't know if that would solve your situation. You might have to use cookies instead. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.